# Copying values in an array to a series of other arrays without a loop

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I'm new to Python, and don't know how to code this nicely (or even to search for the answer).

I'm reading data from a fixed-width file:

```
for line in file:
    dataline = [ line[c[0]:c[1]] for c in columns ]
```

which gives me an array of strings:

```
>>> dataline
['    ', ' 2.447756', '0.674290', '313.2406', ' 35.7290', ' 17.8714', 'PAHFTEN                            ']
```

For each line in the file, I would like to shift each element of `dataline` into a different array, e.g.,

```
dataline[0] ---> arrayA[0]
dataline[1] ---> arrayB[0]
dataline[2] ---> arrayC[0]
```

and so on. How can I do that nicely? Intuitively, I would like to do:

```
[arrayA[0], arrayB[0], arrayC[0], ...] = dataline
```

Comment: @Unstack, seems like you need `zip()`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: did you consider using a `dict`?

Comment: @mishik zip would be the final step. But I think he is asking for making the arrays that will be used in `zip`.

Comment: You can also consider making a list of lists(2D array).

Comment: looks like you need `reduce(lambda x, y: x + [y], zip(arrayA, arrayB, arrayC), [])`

Comment: You could consider using a dictionary as follows: 
columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
dataline = ['    ', ' 2.447756', '0.674290', '313.2406', ' 35.7290', ' 17.8714', 'PAHFTEN                            ']
print dict(zip(columns, dataline))

Comment: @wolfrevo And then append to each dict value for each line of data... I see

Comment: yes. declare an array(!) `datalines=[]` before the for-loop and append the result to it: `datalines.append(dict(zip(columns,dataline)))`. Then you can access e.g. line 4, column 'b' as follows `datalines[3]['b']`

Comment: @robert Sounds like an elegant answer, but I have no idea what it means!

Comment: It's definitely the way to go for the kind of problem you are describing: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/python_programming/python_ch20s03.html these kind of "functional programming" constructs loop implicitly.